# Why do we have to perform a normal APU shutdown if a fuel spillage occurs?

Tags: airbus-a320, aircraft-limitations, apu

I was reading in the limitations chapter of the A320 which stated that if a fuel spillage occurs we have to perform a normal APU shutdown what is the reason behind this?

Comment: My presumption would be because the apu intake is on the bottom of the aircraft. You would not want fuel fumes sucked into it

Comment: Are you asking primarily about why the APU would need to be shut down, or are you asking about why to not perform an abnormal APU shutdown (whatever exactly that would mean)?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling my question is simply pertaining to the reasoning behind it as the earlier procedure didn't require us to shut it down. What is the reason behind doing it now.?

Answer (score 1):

I would reason that any source of ignition,such as an APU or vehicle could ignite the spill causing a fire.